# Determine if SQL connection is local or remote

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcpclient

Am trying to develop an application that runs `sql` scripts either or on a **local** or on a **remote** sql server to update values on the application. The connection status is checked using:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverName, 1433);
```

Once we know that we can listen using the port, I will have to pass the **login credentials** to the SQL server either using Windows/SQL server `authentication`. But the problem is that the application needs to **determine** if the server it is connecting to is local or remote based on which the functionality of the application can vary. 
e.g: Use integrated security if using local windows authentication.

Can anyone please assist me in as to how I would be able to determine if the connection is **remote or local** as based on this my application can be developed to enable different functionality/properties.

Comment: There are a solution for this [here](http://gillesperon.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/snippet-c-detect-if-hostname-or-ip-is.html)

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to

```
select @@SERVERNAME
```

to get the name of the server.